# Play video from local files with WebView React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-native-ios

So here is the point. I have some files downloaded on my device. Because can be video,mp3 or pdf, it can be nice to display it on a webview so its preview system will do the work for me, and I have no necessity to download any external media player.

I have this code
let's assume that this path:

```
const path = 'file:///Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D18AD5B6-22D1-4F57-A162-8A1C5DBCAD7A/data/Containers/Data/Application/BF9347EB-8EDF-45CB-9CFD-08C0C8BE3D5C/Documents/song.mp3';


 <WebView
            javaScriptEnabled
            source={{ uri: path }}
            style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
          />
```

My problem is when I'm trying to load the file, it always raise this error: 
[image]

I suspect it's about the route of the uri. With require It renders an error as well ( module cannot be resolved).

This app is just for Ios, not Android.

Any help will be really appreciate!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it!!!
It was rough but finally, I get it.

1. I did it with a webview finally. What I did:

   ```
   <WebView source={{ html: `<html>
       <body>
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
              <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
               Your browser does not support the video 
          </video>
       </body>
   </html>` }} />
   ```

With this one, thanks to @marx_tseng I injected HTML on the webview, so I took advantage of the media player from the browser.

2. I had to load the video/image/mp3 from the `bundle.js`.It is loading previous when you invoke a webview. In this example, I use RNFetchBlob just to point to the folder that my documents are stored inside my device.

   ```
   const html = `<script src="${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir}/bundle.js"></script> `;
   <WebView
   source={{ baseUrl: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir, html,</Webview>
   ```
3. Finally, this is the code result:

   ```
    const html = `<script 
    src="${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.MainBundleDir}/bundle.js"></script> `;
    <WebView
    source={{ baseUrl: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir, html,
           html: `<html>
                    <body>
                       <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                           <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                  Your browser does not support the video 
                        </video>
                     </body>
                  </html>`
          }}
    />
   ```

Here @plougsgaard Provided with this solution.
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/197

I hope that this answer can help if someone is stuck in the same situation.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[this maybe help you, using html video/audio tag](https://gist.github.com/marxtseng/bc642898d6f8b1ba2723264abf4e314f)

Comment: That's amazing @marx_tseng!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot play video in webview. please use npm packages like [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) it will help you to play videos with more controls

Comment: I was afraid to listen to that...Well, I guess that I will move to this module. Thank you @moorthy.

Comment: Good luck. accept answer if its helpful Thanks. :) happy coding!.

Comment: you can play video using react-native-webview

Comment: Yes, now it's possible but in 2017 it's not available